# Is this use of macros to trace program flow portable and free of major pitfalls?

Tags: c, macros

The program below defines macros START and END that expand to the left and right curly bracket
symbols plus some example tracing code. Is this a portable use of a macro and are there any obvious major problems with this? It compiles fine under gcc --pedantic

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
#define TRACE
    
#ifdef TRACE

#define START       {TRACE_START
#define END         TRACE_END}
#define TRACE_START     printf("ENTERING %s\n", __func__);
#define TRACE_END       printf("LEAVING %s\n", __func__);

#else

#define START   {
#define END }

#endif

int func()
START
    printf ("Hello World %s\n");
END

int main()
START
    func();
END
```

which produces the output

```
ENTERING main
ENTERING func
Hello World

LEAVING func
LEAVING main
```

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review site. While this code seems to work there doesn't seem to be a lot of code to review. Other than validating the macro there doesn't seem to be any point to this code. This question is too hypothetical.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to hide the open brace and close brace within the macros.

Comment: Pseudocode is off-topic.

Comment: It is actually a C language program if you care to look at it. It is a valid construct that makes possible runtime configurable program execution tracing and profiling.